# How to recalculate a field on GROUP

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I have a table like

```
f1|f2|fk
1 | 0|100
1 | 1|200
1 | 2|300
1 | 3|400
2 | 0|300
2 | 1|400
2 | 2|500
```

Where `(f1,f2)` is the PK and fk is a foreign key. There are not many values for fk, about 20. f2 is never more than 3. There are a lot of `(f1,f2)` pairs, however. `(f1,fk)` is `UNIQUE`.

Now, say we are mapping 100 and 200 to A, 300 and 400 to B, 500 to C -- this mapping is a given. We would like `(f1_new,fk_mapped)` to stay `UNIQUE`. This is so far solved roughly by

```
INSERT INTO mapped (f1_new,f2_new,fk_new)
SELECT f1, MIN(f2), CASE fk WHEN 100 THEN A WHEN 200 THEN A END AS fk
FROM origin
GROUP BY f1, fk
```

Now, the problem is that we need to keep f2 values 0, 1, 2 in the mapped table, so this is the desired result:

```
f1_new|f2_new|fk_mapped
1     | 0    |A
1     | 1    |B
2     | 0    |B
2     | 1    |C
```

I really would like to keep this within MySQL.

Comment: I'm confused - you say you want to keep all three values of `f2` in your mapped table, but the desired result you show has no instances where `f2 == 2`?

Comment: He wants to assign new values of `f2`, so they're kept in the 0, 1, 2, ... ordering for a particular value of `f1`. It's a per-f1 rank column.

Comment: Ah. Got it. I'm guessing the fourth row in the first sample table should have `f2 == 3`, then. Especially if `(f1, f2)` is the primary key.

Comment: I fixed the first table, that is really a 3. Is it really more helpful to rewrite this with f1 = entity_id, f2 = delta, f3 = target_id? I can but I am not sure how much that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
INSERT INTO mapped (f1_new, f2_new, fk_new)
SELECT f1_new, f2_new, fk_new from (
    SELECT f1_new, @f2 := if(f1_new = @prev_f1, @f2+1, 0) f2_new, fk_new, @prev_f1 := f1_new
    FROM (select f1 AS f1_new, CASE WHEN fk IN (100, 200) THEN 'A'
                                    WHEN fk in (300, 400) THEN 'B'
                                    WHEN fk = 500 THEN 'C'
                               END AS fk_new
          FROM origin
          GROUP BY f1_new, fk_new
          ORDER BY f1_new, fk_new) new,
         (SELECT @f2 := NULL, @prev_f1 := NULL) vars
    ) x
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bbb9/4)

Comment: I believe the above is great but "not predictable" you can't know whether @prev_f1 := fires first. But `@f2 := if(f1_new = @prev_f1, @f2 + 1, 0) + LEAST(0, @prev_f1 := f1_new)` should work because `+` is left-to-right. Idea from [How to Optimize Rank Data in MySQL](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/03/01/optimize-mysql-rank-data.html)

Comment: Also, per [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html): If you use GROUP BY, output rows are sorted according to the GROUP BY columns as if you had an ORDER BY for the same columns.

Comment: @chx I've seen and used variants of this a number of times. While it might not be guaranteed, in practice I think it always works left to right.