# Is MySQL arithmetic plus left-to-right?

Tags: mysql, operation

Following my comment over at [How to recalculate a field on GROUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542738/how-to-recalculate-a-field-on-group/18542846#18542846) where I try to cheat the

> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

curse of [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) by using the plus operator in the following fashion:

```
SELECT @a + LEAST(0, @a:= @a + 1)
```

Using `LEAST / GREATEST` in this fashion is of course not my idea.

I have tried to find documentation on the execution order of the plus operator but curiously enough, I can't. The [Arithmetic Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/arithmetic-functions.html) manual page has nothing on the topic neither has [Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operator-precedence.html). So, do plus operations always run from left to right or is it also undefined?

Comment: This citation refers to the order of evaluation in the SELECT statement, not to the order of the expression evaluation, read carefully the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html, they write that the order of evaluation in `SELECT @a, (@a:=@a+1), ...` is undefinied, MySql is free to evaluate (@a:=@a+1) first, then @a, even that @a is before (@a:=@a+1) in the SELECT statement

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear what I am after.

Answer (score -1):

A little digging finds this [MySQL bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55840) which contains this YACC snippet (which of course can be found in the real source code tree, for eg. [here](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L1419) ):

```
%left   '-' '+'
```

There we go! It is undocumented but the source easily trumps documentation.

Comment: this is what the parser sees, but then there could be an optimization phase. Furthermore, by looking at the code you may know how things are now, but you can't know how they will be tomorrow

Comment: That defines associativity in the grammar, which merely reflects the ordinary rules of arithmetic. It doesn't define evaluation order at runtime. The thread you cite is about precedence, not associativity.

Comment: Well, then what *is* the answer?

Comment: I think the answer is in the text you have cited

Comment: The order is undefined? That's fairly horrible!